# Factorising after adding a square

Tags: number-theory, factoring

I have been thinking about it for quite some time but am unable to find an answer.

Let $a,b,c,d,e$ be any **distinct** natural numbers. Will the relation :

$(x-a)(x-b)+c^2=(x-d)(x-e)$

ever hold? I am unable to find any such case. We can say that

$(x-2)(x-4)+1^2=(x-3)(x-3)$ but here $d,e$ are not distinct. So, is there any example of the given form or is there any proof that it will never hold. Any kind of help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: It is necessary to solve Diophantine equation when the variables $a,b,c,d,e$ depend on $x$ ?

Comment: @individ Pardon me,but I can't understand what you said. I can say this that $a,b,c,d,e$ are independent of $x$ as shown in example identity.

Comment: It is possible to solve in several variants. As the system is shown below. As well as the number of independent certain way from each other.

Comment: A solution to this is $(x-3)(x-13) + 4^2 = (x-5)(x-11)$.  (Recalled from poking at toy examples with a Quadratic Sieve.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expanding you get

$$a+b=d+e$$
$$ab+c^2=de$$

Let $$m=\frac{a+b}{2}=\frac{d+e}{2}$$ 
Then, there exists $f,g$ such that

$$a=m-f, b=m+f, d=m-g, e=m+g$$
with $m,f,g$ either integers, or half integers.

The relation then reduces to

$$g^2+c^2= f^2$$

This leads to an infinite class of solutions.

Pick $g,c,f$ a pytagorean triple and pick $m$ any integer larger than $f$ and $g$. Then

$$a=m-f, b=m+f, d=m-g, e=m+g, c$$
works.

**Example** If $(f,c,g)=(3,4,5)$ and $m=6$ we have
$$a=1, b=11, c=4, d=3, f=9$$
and indeed
$$(x-1)(x-11)+16=(x-3)(x-9)$$

**P.S.** These represent all solutions with $m,f,g$ integers. The solutions with $m,f,g$ half integers lead to the equation
$$(2g)^2+(2c)^2= (2f)^2$$

where $2g, 2f$ are odd integers and $2c$ is even integer. Then, if you pick $m=\frac{2k+1}{2}$ you have the solution
$$a=m-f, b=m+f, d=m-g, e=m+g, c$$

Comment: I am quite upset. There is no option to give +10.

Comment: You with the signs error. We have to $f$ change $g$ .

Comment: Better to write a formula in General. Decided to end. So the numbers of having a ready answer.

Answer (score 0):

I meant not much different decision. Using Pythagorean triples we get a solution depending on two parameters. Although the system itself:

$$\left\{\begin{aligned}&a+b=d+e\\&ab+c^2=de\end{aligned}\right.$$

Can have solutions depend on 3 parameters, for example:

$$a=s(p-k)$$

$$b=p^2+s(p+s-k)$$

$$d=s(p+s-k)$$

$$e=p^2+s(p-k)$$

$$c=ps$$

$p,s,k$ - integers, any sign.